# JSF/CDI: General way to update page content

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

what is the general way when requesting new pages with given parameters, i.e. calling CDI bean operations and bind the outcome to the page components?

I am using this 'pattern', but is this the right way?

```
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="dataForm">

            #{userForm.init(param.id, param.mode)}

            <!--  User edit Dialog -->
            <p:panel>
            ...
             </:panel>
         </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

The problem is that when using the 'rendered' attribute, this depends on the bean (non-blocking) process outcome but the page might be rendered faster. Thus, I should be able to call an update process on the page UI components after processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JSF 2.2 the way to go is:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{backingBean.action}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

If you are < JSF2.2 but you happen to be using Seam you could use something like this as a pre-render view event, it does not have to be in a template, you can drop it in your `ui:composition`

**XHTML**

```
xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/seam/faces"
```

---

```
<f:metadata>
    <s:viewAction action="#{backingBean.action}" />
</f:metadata>
```

here is something to read [Seam3](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/components.html#d0e454), if not you can always use the classic way:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{backingBean.entryId}"/>  
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{backingBean.loadEntry}"/>  
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: Note that JSF-2.2 finally added `f:viewAction`, which does what `s:viewAction` is doing in your example.

Comment: thanks for the info, I'm however stuck with 2.1 so thats the best way for me. Good point though!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I read something about \@PostConstruct annotation. Would this be a suitable alternative when using \@ConversationScope for the form beans?

Comment: you would use `@PostConstruct` to initialize a bean onece it has been created and all its dependencies are injected to perform actions on them. If you want to use some logic that deals with properies that you set with `<f:viewParam>` like id, pageName etc. `<f:viewAction>` is the way to go.

Comment: Hmmm. I get the message: ... have the property 'action'. Do i really need to call backingBean.action()?

Comment: You can call whatever method you want and pass whatever params you want.